# Creating a single driver to traverse multiple sites using proxies

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium making use of proxies to parse the title of different sites. My script can do it if I stick to create individual driver instance for every site. However, my goal here is to make use of the same browser (using different proxies) no matter how many sites it traverses.

***How can I use the same browser with different proxies to traverse multiple sites to parse the title of them?***

My attempt so far with:

```
import random
from itertools import cycle
from selenium import webdriver

proxyList = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def get_title(url):
    random.shuffle(proxyList)
    proxy = next(cycle(proxyList))
    print(f'proxy in use {proxy}')
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print(driver.title)
    except Exception:
        if proxy in proxyList:
            proxyList.remove(proxy)
        return get_title(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = ['http://www.google.com/','https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.yahoo.com/']
    for link in links:
        get_title(link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the driver once and pass it to the function instead of creating it in the function.
This also means that the same proxy is used all the time...

As the proxy is passed as an argument before the chromedriver is started it can’t be changed without creating a new driver.

```
import random
from itertools import cycle
from selenium import webdriver

proxyList = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def get_title(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.shuffle(proxyList)
    proxy = next(cycle(proxyList))
    print(f'proxy in use {proxy}')
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    links = ['http://www.google.com/','https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.yahoo.com/']
    for link in links:
        get_title(link, driver)
```

Comment: Would be thankful if you show me how @SimonF. You are really a master on this proxy related issues.

Comment: The problem with keeping using the same driver is that the proxy is the same all the time.

Comment: @robots.txt Would you mind marking the answer as correct if it answered your question or stating what is missing? You have done the same thing on other questions as well, so you should look through them also. Thanks

Comment: Already accepted @SimonF. So, there is no way to create a single instance of driver and reuse it while using proxies, right?